Dropping WP database, when not visible anywhere
I am constantly getting errors in mysql_errors.log (XAMMP) for a database which I cannot find. Here is one example.
2024-06-25 10:37:24 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``wp`.`wp_woocommerce_shipping_zone_methods``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.

The problem is that I cannot find this database on my xammp installation. Running DROP like
DROP DATABASE wp 

The output is:
10:41:35    drop database wp    Error Code: 1008. Can't drop database 'wp'; database doesn't exist  0.016 sec

Any ideas on how to find it and delete it?
In MySQL/data there is no such folder

Duplicate of DBA - InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'database/table'. Mariadb 10.1.40 ?

Are you sure the logged in DB user has the permission to access the wp schema?

What you have is a manually deleted database.
Recreate the database directory by creating the wp folder in your datadir. CREATE DATABASE wp will discover the missing table space.
Then recreate fake table definition - as a file wp_woocommerce_shipping_zone_methods.frm in the wp directory. Its contents don't matter and it can be empty.
Look at the output from the following query to see if there are any other .frm files that need to be created:
 SELECT NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_TABLES WHERE NAME LIKE "wp/%"

Then DROP DATABASE wp to remove the database again and all the lingering table elements.
Note for next time, use DROP DATABASE first and don't play with with database files directly.
